# Exporting directly from another CommonJS module

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

I'm using CommonJS and Browserify, is there anything wrong with creating a module that all it does is to unite exports from other modules? For example:

```
var submodule1 = require('sub-module-1');
var submodule2 = require('sub-module-2');

module.exports = {
  widget1: submodule1.widget1,
  widget2: submodule2.widget2,
  widget3: submodule2.widget3,
};
```

Comment: Also, just an fyi, `module.exports` defaults to an object, so you don't have to redefine it. You can just do `exports.widget1 = submodule1.widget1` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's nothing "wrong" with this. It's up to your discretion how best to modularize and package your code so that it makes the most sense for you, your colleagues and fellow developers.